# Idiom for doing anything to get what you want

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I'm looking for an idiom which describes a person who does everything to get what he wants even by being dishonest.

Comment: Lots. See also: *pull all stops*, *go all out*, *go all the way*, ..., in addition to those already suggested.

Comment: He'd step over his own mother to make a buck. https://youtu.be/ToTRAhmnxls?t=52

Answer (score 2):

People who will do anything to get what they want will **stop at nothing**.

Here is the definition in the *[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stop-at-nothing)*:

> If you stop at nothing to achieve something, you are willing to do
> anything in order to achieve it, even if it involves danger, great
> effort, or harming other people:

Four authentic examples from Google:

> - Headline: Parents *stop at nothing* to find cure for son.
> - It is clear that he will *stop at nothing* to win Beck's heart.
> - Many people want the live trade ceased and they'll *stop at nothing* to ensure that happens.
> - I recognize that the church must *stop at nothing* to root out sexual abuse.

Answer (score 2):

The closest idiom for this situation is ***by hook or crook***; also (synonym) ***by any means***.

TFD(idioms):

> **[by hook or (by) crook](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/by+hook+or+crook)**
>   by any means, legal or illegal.
>   I'll get the job done by hook or by crook.
>   I must have that house. I intend
>   to get it by hook or crook.
>
> McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. © 2002 by
>   The McGraw-Hill Companies, Inc.
>
> **[by any means](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/by+any+means)**
>   In any possible way. Often used in the negative.
>   We need to court that big investor by any means, so
>   shameless flattery is a fine place to start!
>
> Farlex Dictionary of Idioms. © 2015 Farlex, Inc, all rights reserved.

Answer (score 0):

The expression **at all costs** (or **at any cost**) is an all-inclusive phrase in that not only does it mean that you're so determined to achieve something that you're ready to pay a high price for it, but it can also be used to mean that you're even ready to resort to methods that might be considered dishonest to achieve your goals. Here's how [**the Free Dictionary**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/at+all+costs) defines this idiom:

> Regardless of the expense or effort involved; by any means.

Example sentence (taken from [the Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/at_all_costs_(or_at_any_cost))):

> It seems that their agenda is growth **at any cost** regardless of the wishes of the people.

Answer (score 0):

I favor the single word **unscrupulous** to describe a person who will do *anything*, including breaking any ethical code, to get what they want.

Merriam-Webster [describes](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unscrupulous) this as "unprincipled," and the American Heritage Dictionary [expands](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=unscrupulous) on its sense of being dishonest:

> Having or showing no regard for what is right or honorable; devoid of scruples.

The benefit of the single word is that it is flexible to context. Someone is unscrupulous, acts in an unscrupulous manner, or even does something unscrupulously.

Some examples:

> [John of Gaunt](https://books.google.com/books?id=jdw5AAAAcAAJ&lpg=PA130&ots=LzFIpLcQaz&dq=A%20person..boundless%20in%20ambition%2C%20and%20unscrupulous%20in%20his%20choice%20of%20means%20for%20gratifying%20it.&pg=PA130#v=onepage&q=A%20person..boundless%20in%20ambition,%20and%20unscrupulous%20in%20his%20choice%20of%20means%20for%20gratifying%20it.&f=false) had been represented as a person of the haughtiest nature and the most despotic principles of conduct, dark, insidious, and crafty, boundless in ambition, and **unscrupulous in his choice of means for gratifying it**.
>
> [The fact is](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2017/05/how-to-build-your-own-vpn-if-youre-rightfully-wary-of-commercial-options/), ISPs tend to be pretty **unscrupulous**, sometimes even ruthless, **about how they gather and use their customers' data**.
>
> [He acknowledged](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2676276) that " the cost of being poor has always been exorbitant, " as **unscrupulous landlords and creditors have developed a vulture-like ability to feed off of poverty**.